# "How much X is in Y?" vs "How much X is there in Y?"

Tags: questions, there-is

First:

> How much money **is there** in a bank?

Second:

> How much money **is** in a bank?

Honestly, both of them are the same for me, but who knows.. I am not a native speaker.

Comment: I am a native speaker, an while, juxtaposed like that, I read a subtle difference in the two sentences, it is very minor indeed. It is mostly fair to say they are identical.

Comment: There is no significant difference.  It's just that, in a given situation, one may "feel" better than the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the two sentences have little, if any, difference in meaning, there are contexts where one variant is more natural than the other. For example.

> A: There are 10 boxes in the room. Some of them are on the table.
>
> B: How many boxes are on the table?

Here, "How many boxes are *there* on the table" would be slightly awkward.

On the other hand, consider the following dialog:

> A: There's virtually no room on my table.
>
> B: What item takes up most space?
>
> A: Books
>
> B: How many books are there on your table?

Here, "How many books are on your table" would be slightly awkward.

I think that *How many books are on your table?* has a vague implication of *"We know that some of the books are on the table. The question is how many are, and where are the rest."*. *"How many books are there on the table"* focuses more on the items on the table and the main question is *"How many of these items are books?"*.